# How do I use a pre-downloaded tar balls file (.tar.gz) to help with the installation?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install iRedMail on my ubuntu 18.04 following [this link](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-18-04-iredmail-email-server).

I've ran these commands.

```
wget https://github.com/iredmail/iRedMail/archive/1.3.2.tar.gz
tar xvf 1.3.2.tar.gz
cd iRedMail-1.3.2/
chmod +x iRedMail.sh
sudo bash iRedMail.sh
```

during the execution of `sudo bash iRedMail.sh` I'm being stuck at

```
...    
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
[ INFO ] Fetching source tarballs ...
[ INFO ] + 1 of 5: https://dl.iredmail.org/yum/misc/iRedAdmin-1.2.tar.gz
```

which indicates that my ubuntu has some difficulty in connecting to dl.iredmail.org.

I've download the file 'iRedAdmin-1.2.tar.gz' manually, how do I use it to help the installation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what commands you are running. You only show output but not what command you ran.

Comment: My approach would be: use edit to open iRedMail.sh check what the connection does and replace it by what it should be. 1.2 might not be valid anymore.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18. Maybe 18.04?